# Mongoose saves in UTC but needs to retrieve in different timezones depends on the user timezone

Tags: express, datetime, mongoose, timezone

Mongoose saves all dates in UTC format that's OK.

Each user has a specific timezone. It stores the in user's document.

I would like to send any documents to the client with converted dates in the user's timezone.

I know how to format one value, but I'm looking for a solution to avoid transformation one-by-one.

The workaround solution will be a pass-through transform function on the client for each value or recursive modification response.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in aggregation.

Lets say you have this data:

```json
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5f18b5c87f9f9c0fd8322b60"
    },
    "createdAt": {
      "$date": "2020-07-22T21:55:20.575Z"
    },
    
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "5f19efac5cfa75483865eaa2"
    },
    "createdAt": {
      "$date": "2020-07-23T20:14:36.108Z"
    },
  }
]
```

you can do this:

```js
const timezone = "America/Chicago"

Model.aggregate([
    {
        $set: {
            localTime: {
                $dateToString: {
                    date: "$createdAt",
                    timezone
                }
            }
        },
    }
]);
```

The result of the aggregation will be:

```js
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5f18b5c87f9f9c0fd8322b60"),
    "createdAt": ISODate("2020-07-22T21:55:20.575Z"),
    "localTime": "2020-07-22T16:55:20.575Z"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5f19efac5cfa75483865eaa2"),
    "createdAt": ISODate("2020-07-23T20:14:36.108Z"),
    "localTime": "2020-07-23T15:14:36.108Z"
  }
]
```

Demo example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/7IOGMrC2sf5